# Order index according to a column in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have created a dataframe using pd.cut and adding after the last two rows. I would like to know how I can sort the index according to the column Interval.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8Z2p.png)

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to use `sort_values()` here, and then `reset_index()`. Assuming your dataframe is called `df`:

```
df = df.sort_values(by = 'Interval', ascending = True)
df = df.reset_index(drop = True)
```

This will reset the index to increase incrementally with the value of the interval.
Then, if you still want your dataframe sorted according to the frequency in each bin, you can just sort again:

```
df = df.sort_values(by = 'Frequency', ascending = False)
```